# .gitignore for Visual Studio cmake - which files should I ignore?

Tags: git, visual-studio, cmake, gitignore

Making a C++ application in Visual Studio 2019 with cmake, Visual Studio generates output in a folder called "out". However, there are some ninja build files like *.ninja_deps*, *rules.ninja*, and *build.ninja*.

Tried Visual Studio .gitignore from *github/gitignore repository*, but that only ignores *.vs* folder.

Which files should I ignore?

Answer (score 2):

In general, you should not need to track any *generated* files in your repository. You should check your `CMakeLists.txt` file into your repository because this is code that *you* control, and it controls what is generated in `out`. However, all of the CMake-generated build files or outputs placed in the `out` directory generally should **not** need to be modified, and can be ignored from a source control perspective. These generated build files will often vary from person-to-person on your team (depending on their Visual Studio version, project location within the filesystem, preferences, etc.), so checking these files into source control can be a nightmare. Therefore, my recommendation is, just append a line to your `.gitignore` file to ignore the entire `out` directory:

```
...

# Visual Studio 2019 cache/options directory
.vs/

# Add this line
out/
```

---

In fact, the `.gitignore` [template file](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) for Visual Studio **already** ignores several directories where *generated* build files are typically placed. You can simply add `out/` to the end of this list to ignore the CMake-based build results as well.

```
# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
x64/
x86/
[Ww][Ii][Nn]32/
[Aa][Rr][Mm]/
[Aa][Rr][Mm]64/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
[Ll]og/
[Ll]ogs/
# Add this line
out/
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I add the out folder to my .gitignore and run the program, it opens an empty console window, instead of running the program. It got fixed when I undid the change.

Comment: @rohan How are you running the program? Be sure an appropriate Startup item is selected before running - this should be the same Startup item that worked before the change.

Comment: The startup item was the .exe file that was in the out folder

Comment: @rohan I'm still not sure *how* you run your program (e.g. `F5` key), but updating the gitignore files *shouldn't* affect how the program is executed. It should only affect your git configuration. It sounds like something else might be going on with your setup, as I'm not able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The project is loaded in folder view. If I load it in solution view, it says the project was unloaded. In the directory, there is no project file. When I click run, it executes some commands, and the runs the exe.

Comment: The default .gitignore for a CMake configuration still does not include the `out` _or_ the `.vs` folder (the one that gets created when initializing a solution git repo from within VS). Annoying...